# Behaviour of multiple inbound channel adapters/pollers in a single context

Tags: spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration context with multiple inbound channel adapters, each with his own poller (currently all the pollers have their refresh time configured with fixed-delay but may use fixed-rate in future). All the inbound adapters output their produced messages to the same processing chain. The question is what is the behaviour of polling and message consuming in such a situation? Imagine, that poller #1 has produced 1000 messages and they are handed to my processing chain. Since processing can take some significant time it is possible that it has come time for the poller #2 to do its job and possibly produce messages. But remeber - my processing chain is still handling messages passed by poller #1. What happens?

1. Poller #2 is not run at all until all the poller #1 messages are processed.
2. Poller #2 is run (but how could it be run if we have only one thread?), its messages are stored for later use when all the poller #1 messages are processed.
3. Processing initiated by poller #1 is interrupted, poller #2 is run, produced  messages are passed to the processing chain immediately.
4. Some other answer

Note that all my channels are direct channels and there are no task executors used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pollers are independent tasks handled by the common `taskScheduler` bean; as long as the task scheduler has sufficient threads, there is no coordination across pollers.

If the pool is exhausted, pollers will run "late".

By default the `taskScheduler` has 10 threads; but you can [reconfigure it](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler).

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same case, however the behaviour is a bit differs.

My case is :

1. I have 4 pollers which requests data independently from 4 different
   **blocking queues** ( i have set up timeout for 1 sec for each of them)
2. I have 4 inbound channel adapters configured to use fixed-delay (100ms) and the pollers above (one to one).
3. I have thread pool with 4 threads core/max, configured to handle inbound channel adapters (all adapters use this pool)

And now i see at logs that each thread executes all pollers sequently, and if there is an empty queue (i am using **blocking queue**) then all threads are delayed for 1 sec. **This means even if you have enough threads you still may get delay for all your threads if at least one poller is slow.** For instance if I would not use timeout for queue reading at all then all threads would stop on empty queue and nothing would be read from all others non-empty queues .

To solve this issue I guess we need to configure separate thread pools for each poller<-->inbound channel adapter.